# How can I prevent Visual Studio from warning about a lack of debugging information?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

How do I prevent VS from showing user the following warning:

> No Debugging Information
>   Debugging information for 'MyExe.exe' cannot be found or does not match. Cannot find or open the PDB file. Do you want to continue debugging?

In my situation the user of my product wants to develop a plugin and (s)he want to debug it. There is appropriate configuration in VC++ project so that when (s)he presses F5 then my application will start and load the plugin. However, VS complains about lack of debugging information. While in general lack of valid debugging information is a valid concern, in this case I don't want to deliver .pdb file for MyExe.exe (user has no reason to debug my MyExe.exe application). Is there a way to prevent VS from searching for debugging information for MyExe.exe?

Comment: Check what is set on `Generate Debug Info` under `Project Propeties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Debugging`. That should be set to `Yes(/DEBUG)` to avoid `No Debugging Information Debugging information for 'MyExe.exe'`

Comment: Never tried that but what about giving a "stub" PDB? Empty file, or a real PDB that was generated for an "empty" MyExe.exe, or something like that.

Comment: @Mahesh: The value was set to /YES, but it requires deploying .pdb file and I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which version and edition of VS your customer is using, but at least in VS 2005 and VS 2010, open  Tools->Options->Debugging->General, there is a list of settings, scroll down, find the "Warn if no symbols on launch (Native only)" setting and clear the check mark.

I *believe* that this will accomplish what you're looking for, in that the dialog won't pop up unless/until the debugger stops in your code.  If it stops (or hits a breakpoint) in the customer's plugin, then it should be able to find the symbols, and I think it won't cause the popup.

Comment: I'm using VS2008/VS2010. I was hoping for project level setting but it seems there is only global option (that I should probably not modify for my users)...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can turn off VS's messaging about missing or mismatched PDB's, however, you might be able to create PDB using the [`/PDBSTRIPPED` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y87kw2fd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) when building -- this will give the user a .pdb containing minimal information (just the public symbols, basically).

Comment: Unfortunately VS still shows the warning if I use the minimal .pdb file. The text is slightly different: 'Symbols loaded (source information stripped).', but I cannot consider this as a solution to my problem...

Comment: Why is it so important to hide the message? Don't these appear in the output window anyhow? I don't think you can do anything about them, short of maybe writing a VS add-in to replicate the functionality of the output window but allow you to strip certain messages out.

Comment: It's not in the output window, it is a big ugly dialog box. Ok, it is not a critical issue, but still it would be nice to prevent it from popping up as it will just cause confusion.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, I don't think I've ever seen a dialog box with that message in it. That would be more annoying, hm...

Comment: 'My' dialog has 'do not show again' checkbox. Maybe after checking it it will just show in the output window (cannot check right now)... But where is the information saved/how do I change this setting from my code (vspackage).